# Javafx starting but not running

Tags: java, javafx, fxml

My javafx application starts up but its not running after build with e(fx)clipse. Straight from eclipse it works just fine. Running it with java -jar Djavafx.verbose=true does not give any errors. Project can be found on http://viped.net/simplememoTiny.zip if somebody want's to look it and give some help.

Comment: How are you exporting?